# How to wait for inside for each to complete before iterating to next loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

Hi I want to implement nested for each. But for loop should not iterate to next until nested for loop completes its execution. I have tried with `asyn.forEachOf`  but first for loop executed without waiting for second for loop. I have implemented like this

```
async.forEachOf(playerIds, function (playerId, key, playerCallback) {
    console.log(playerId);
    //Find coach rating for every player's goals
    DateInfo.find({
        coachId: userId,
        playerId: playerId,
        coachRemoved: false
    }).select('objectiveId frequencyId').populate({
        path: 'objectiveId', match: {'deleted': {$ne: 2}}, select: {'name': 1}
    }).exec(function (error, coachDateInfos) {
        if (error) {
            response.status(200).json({message: error});
        } else {
            console.log(coachDateInfos);
            playerCallback()
        }
    })
});
```

I haven't posted inside async function. I have two player Ids it prints two player ids first then it prints coachDateInfos.

Answer (score 1):

That's because a `for-loop` is a **synchronous** action while `Model.find().exec()` is an **asynchronous** action. You can't mix the two together. You can do the following (no `async` lib):

```
app.get(async (req, res) => {
  const promises = []

  playerIs.forEach(playerId => {
    const promise = DateInfo
      .find({coachId: userId, playerId, coachRemoved: false})
      .select('objectiveId frequencyId')
      .populate({path: 'objectiveId', match: {'deleted': {$ne: 2}}, select: {'name': 1})
      .exec()

      promises.push(promise)
  })

  try {
    res.json(await Promise.all(promises))
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(200).json(err);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayOfFuncs = [];
for (var key in playerIds) {
    let player = playerIds[key];
    let func_1 = function(playerId,cb)
    {
        console.log(playerId);
        //Find coach rating for every player's goals
        DateInfo.find({
            coachId: userId,
            playerId: playerId,
            coachRemoved: false
        }).select('objectiveId frequencyId').populate({
            path: 'objectiveId', match: {'deleted': {$ne: 2}}, select: {'name': 1}
        }).exec(function (error, coachDateInfos) {
            if (error) {
                //response.status(200).json({message: error});
                cb(error, null);
            } else {
                console.log(coachDateInfos);
                cb(null, coachDateInfos);
            }
        })
    }
    arrayOfFuncs.push(func_1.bind(null,player));
}

async.parallel(arrayOfFuncs, function(errString, allResults) {
    if(errString) {
        console.log(errString);
    } else {
        console.log(allResults);
    }
})
```

Comment: it is showing error  let func_1 = function(playerIds[key],cb){
                                                   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: currently I'm having two players , but it always takes 2nd player only